# Obtain full-page screenshot from WebBrower component

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser, screenshot

I am attempting to capture a full-page screenshot of any website a user is viewing using the `WebBrowser` component.

At present, I am able to only able to capture what a user is viewing from within the `WebBrowser`. However, the screenshot image created is the size of the webpage. For example, below is a (half-sized) screenshot of the BBC website, the black area is actually saved transparent but I've filled it black for visibility.

[image: Failed screenshot of the BBC website]

I have seen solutions where a new `WebBrowser` instance is used to fetch a fullpage snapshot. However, I need the screenshot to be exactly of the page as the user is viewing it at the time, much like how the full-page screenshot works in Firefox.

My code below that generated the above image:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        int scrollWidth = 0;
        int scrollHeight = 0;

        scrollHeight = webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
        scrollWidth = webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
        webBrowser1.Size = new Size(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);

        webBrowser1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height));
        bm.Save(@"D:\Screenshots\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);


  }
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the PNG returned from the DrawToBitmap. Can you check how much percent of the image generated is black? Is it two thirds, or something like that? 

Another line might be the image size. DrawToBitmap function might just be unfit for you, since i assume it fills nulls and blackspaces instead of lowering the file resolution. Try to look into other alternatives (Maybe something that works with JPEG?)

Comment: @A.Abramov: I presume the issue is that `DrawToBitmap` probably renders at the current size of the web browser *control* but he wants to render the whole page.

Comment: @Dark Falcon I dont believe so, since that'd crop the picture **before** the web browser, and here we're talking about too much **after** the website itself in the image.

Comment: @A.Abramov: If you look at the bottom of the image, there is clearly more web page not rendered. There is a heading right at the bottom and the picture appears too short. In looking at the code, I see he tries to resize the control to the scroll size of the page. My guess would be that while the control is now big enough, it has not completed recomputing the page layout.

Comment: I do believe this issue lies within `DrawToBitmap`, as sometimes it generates a purely white page. Although I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a good working one..

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       using (FileDialog fd = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            fd.Filter = "Image (*.png)|*.png";
            if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                new WebPageSnap(webBrowser1.Url.ToString(), fd.FileName);
                //might take 3 or 4 seconds to save cauz it has to load again.
            }
        }
    }

    class WebPageSnap
    {
        WebBrowser wb;
        string outFile;

        public WebPageSnap(string url, string outputFile)
        {
            wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.ProgressChanged += wb_ProgressChanged;
            outFile = outputFile;
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            wb.Navigate(url);
        }

        void wb_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CurrentProgress == e.MaximumProgress)
            {
                wb.ProgressChanged -= wb_ProgressChanged;
                try
                {
                    int scrollWidth = 0;
                    int scrollHeight = 0;

                    scrollHeight = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
                    scrollWidth = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
                    wb.Size = new Size(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);


                    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
                    for (int Xcount = 0; Xcount < bitmap.Width; Xcount++)
                        for (int Ycount = 0; Ycount < bitmap.Height; Ycount++)
                            bitmap.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, Color.Black);
                    wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
                    bitmap.Save(outFile, ImageFormat.Png);
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

    }
```

.

```
;Here's the result
```

.

[image]

Comment: The main thing i've seen after experimenting is that, webbrowser control which is being visible and currently used, is not able to drawtoBitmap. Instantiate a new one without adding it to the form anywhere, apply the url to it, load and capture the image..

Comment: This is a nice and clever answer. Unfortunately, due to the nature of the project the screenshot *must* be of the current page as it is being viewed.

Comment: Why can't u do like this?, When user clicks a button, you open a filesave dialog, when DialogResult.OK, then use like -----> new WebPageSnap(webBrowser1.Url.ToString(), fileDialog1.FileName);

Comment: Your current browser control wont be interrupted, and the image can be saved. Do you need an explanation?

Comment: could it be performed on a button click after the page has loaded? I really do appreciate your effort, thank you.

Comment: This solution requires a  new browser instance. The screenshot must be of the current site as it is being viewed, sadly. A website's content could change if it is reloaded, and for this application that would be no good. Thank you again.